# Trying to rename files using capture groups in bash

Tags: regex, bash

I have a bunch of image files out of google takeout in folders of the format yyyy-MM-dd/img.jpg - I use phockup to organize my photos and it needs the photos to be in yyyy/mm/dd folders. I'd like to keep the dates since google already gave me them.

For example - this folder/image should match

/2018-07-01/test_img.jpg

and be renamed to

/2018/07/01/test_img.jpg

I've tried using bash together with sed and find to use regex capture groups to move the files, but I don't seem to have had much luck. see below for where I currently am

```sh
find . -name "*.jpg" -print0 | sed 'p;s/([0-9]{4})\-([0-9]{2})\-([0-9]{2})\/(.*)/$2\/$3\/$4\/$5/' | xargs -0 -n2 mv
```

Here is the error I'm getting

mv: cannot move './2018-07-01/test_img.jpg' to ''$'\n''./2018-07-01/test_img.jpg': No such file or directory

Which seems odd since the regex capture groups I believe are correct. I'm not sure why it won't rename the files.

Comment: `sed` *basic regex* does not support `{n}` occurrences. Use `sed -r` instead.

Comment: `sed -r 's/([0-9]{4})\-([0-9]{2})\-([0-9]{2})\/(.*)/\1\/\2\/\3\/\4/'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a bash possibility. Run the script in the directory with the date-named directories. I used a copy command instead of move so you can check the results before deleting the old files. If you want to use mv instead, at least run it once with echo in front of it for a sanity check.

```
newdir=/home/me/newpics

[[ -d "$newdir"  ]] || mkdir "$newdir"

for dir in *; do
  if [[ -d "$dir" && "$dir" =~ ([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+) ]]; then
      year=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
      month=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
      day=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}

      todir="$newdir/$year"; [[ -d "$todir"  ]] || mkdir "$todir"
      todir+="/$month";      [[ -d "$todir"  ]] || mkdir "$todir"
      todir+="/$day";        [[ -d "$todir"  ]] || mkdir "$todir"

      for file in "$dir/"*.jpg; do
        base=$(basename "$file")
        cp "$file" "$todir/$base"
      done
  fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks - this worked and is probably more straightforward to use than the one-liner full of regexp I was trying to use

Answer (score 1):

In addition to my comments above, and that to use `{n}` occurrences you will need more than *basic* regex expression, if I understand correctly you only want to match `.jpg` files with the format, e.g. `/2018-07-01/test_img.jpg`, then you will either need to limit the `find` expression to only find files in the date-formatted directories, or you can have `sed` only pass along files from those directories. `sed` provides the ability to only match lines of a given format before attempting the substitution using the form:

```
sed -r /match/s/find/replace/
```

(**note:** the `-r` option causes `sed` to use *extended* regular expressions, check the manual page (`man sed`) to ensure your version supports that option as well, `-E` is often used for the same purpose)

For for your `match` above, you can use:

```
/^\/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/
```

Additionally, the `-n` option to `sed` suppresses the default printing of output. So to craft an expression that only acts on and passes the appropriate files along to `xargs`, you could use the following `sed` expression:

```
sed -r -n '/^\/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/s/([0-9]{4})\-([0-9]{2})\-([0-9]{2})\/(.*)/\1\/\2\/\3\/\4/p'
```

(**note:** the replacement of `'$'` with `\` to invoke the wanted *backreference* and adjusting the backreference number to `1-4` instead of `2-5`, and adding `p` after the substitution causes `sed` to print those lines that matched the expression)